# Failure in delete performance counter category

Tags: c#, performancecounter, perfmon

I have this simple code:

```
public void CreateCounters() {
    if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(_categoryName)) {
        PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(_categoryName);
    }

    // create logic…
}
```

works on my machine.
I run it on my server, get the following stack trace:

```
System has detected a fatal error. EXITING... 
NativeErrorCode: 1010 
ErrorCode: -2147467259 
Message: The configuration registry key is invalid 
TargetSite: Void RegisterFiles(System.String, Boolean) 
HelpLink:  
Source: System 
Stack Trace: 
 at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.RegisterFiles(String arg0, Boolean unregister) 
 at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(String categoryName) 
 at myApp.Common.Utils.PerformanceCounters.PerformanceCounters.CreateCounters() 
 at myApp.Common.Utils.PerformanceCounters.myAppPerformanceCounterReporter.Init() 
 at myApp.Common.Utils.PerformanceCounters.myAppPerformanceCounterReporter.get_Instance() 
 at myApp.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The category exists on the server, I can see it in `perfmon` GUI.

Comment: Is it possible that this is a permissions issue?

Comment: is the performance counter category `_categoryName` created by you or is one of the predefined categroies?

Comment: This is custom categroty name that I create. I'm not sure if this is permission issue (it is not implied), but I run under administrative rights...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok this is some error in performance counter mechanis, that should be fixed by the following script :

```
cd %systemroot%\system32
lodctr /R
```

check out this link : http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2008/08/10/possible-performance-counter-corruption-or-performance-counters-are-just-disabled.aspx